# How to lock a file with git on BitBucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-lfs

I am dealing with large files and have done `git lfs install` and followed all the steps listed [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-lfs#locking-files). But when I actually want to lock a file, i.e. `git lfs lock <filename>` I am getting the following error:

> Lock failed: Repository or object not found:
>   https://bitbucket.org/%7B%7D/%7B6cc70c4a-2d65-4a6d-b827-c37e61c63245%7D/info/lfs/locks
>
> Check that it exists and that you have proper access to it

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 2):

This may be a little late to answer this question, but for the benefit of those looking for answer to the same question, let me put it here.
Installing `lfs` is not sufficient to start tracking large files. We need to tell Git which files to track as large files by the LFS using the `git lfs track` command.
If you want to be able to ‘lock’ these files, you must also include the `--lockable` flag.

For example:

```
git lfs track '<pattern>' --lockable
```

This needs to be done for each repository.

For more information see documentation https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-lfs#locking-files